# Annoying System Beep Won't Stop?

Tags: sound, dell, 17.10

I have a Dell Pc (Dell Inspiron N5110) with an annoying beep sound (5 successive beep every 6 or 7 seconds).

I was able to mute this sound using ubuntu version 16.04 with pm-suspend command. On Windows 7 the sound turn off just after the loading screen of the system.

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10 but this sound won't stop at all.
Now I can't do anything at all.

I know that the system talking to me with this annoying sound so I tried everything : change the RAM, new CMOS battery, cleaning, tried some solutions on the internet during the last 3 years but really I can't find an appropriate solution to mute this sound !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.
These beeps lived with my PC for years (1 year after I bought it), until I used to hear them all the time with different aspect :

- Five beeps only at the beginning.
- Five beeps the whole time.

I thought it was a manufacturing defect so I tried to ignore it since it comes after only 1 year and I already cleaned the PC one years ago !
I was trying to mute the sound until my PC turns off these two days showing this message "Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled". Serious hardware problem.

I cleaned the fan (wasn't very dusty), changed the CMOS battery, **cleaned the processor from the old thermal paste and changed it.**

Even the fan now don't run rarely. Looks like a new laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can disable the motherboard speaker (although it is disabled by default).

```
#   @doc https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PC_speaker
grep 'pcspk' /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Comment: It's already disabled 'pcspkr'